# configuring all interfaces from MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

I have a set of machines in MAAS with 4 nics.  How do I get a juju deploy to bring up all nics?  My Ceph deploy is failing because the right interfaces have not been brought up.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a workaround.  Rather then doing a

```
deploy --config ... -n 3 ceph ...
```

I did

```
juju machine add --constraints ...
```

This deployed the machine and installed the juju client software on the machine.  I could then go in and add the `ifup ethx` lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ifup` the interfaces.  Then I could do my deploy one machine at a time with

```
juju deploy --config ... ceph --constraints ... --to X
```

Answer (score 0):

MAAS currently does not support this feature. We are actively working on the ability for MAAS to perform this operation. This is a key feature in MAAS 1.9 and will be released with Ubuntu 15.10.

**MAAS 1.9+ Now Supports Interface Configuration** - on the machine details page you can now configure all the interfaces. Including bonding, VLAN's, and aliases. MAAS 2.1 supports creating bridges as well.

Comment: Is there a workaround that I can do until then?

Comment: Updated the answer. But use 1.9+ and you can configure the interfaces.